# EditText input type text password not changing

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-appwidget, android-inputtype

I want to change the input type of an edit text to visible when a switch is checked.

```
Switch a =(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    a.setText("visible");
    a.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
                pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            }else{      
                EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
                pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }
        }
    });
```

It works when I turn on the switch and makes the password visible but when I turn it off it remains visible and doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

Try this in your else statement for showing the password type variation. The reason is because it needs to specify that the input class is of the type text.

Comment: How to write | in layout file when using data binding.I tried this: android:inputType='@{oneField.IsMasked==true ? (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) : InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT }' It doesn't compile